# Solving intercept / equivalence point / crossing point of where two Weibull regressions meet

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, weibull-distribution

I'm looking to solve the point where 2 opposite **Weibull** functions meet.  I'm using the [drc package](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/drc/index.html), with a type 2 Weibull having 2 parameters in `R`. I've fit both lines to my data, and now I have the *e* and *b* intercepts for the functions defining each line.  I would like to now solve for where the x values are equivalent.

The **Weibull (type2) 2 parameter** function is:
$$
f(x)= 1-\exp\left[-\exp\left(b\times (\log(x) - \log(e)\right))\right]
$$
exponential decay line:

```
           Estimate Std. Error   t-value p-value
 b:(Intercept) -2.226194   0.225339 -9.879323       0
 e:(Intercept)  1.209326   0.072042 16.786444       0
```

exponential increase line:

```
               Estimate Std. Error   t-value p-value
b:(Intercept)  1.616248   0.145047 11.142956       0
e:(Intercept)  1.837511   0.072107 25.482970       0
```

Ideally I would also like to get a confidence interval for this point. I have this run in R so if I could input a suggested code that would be great.

This is for a paper I'm writing, and I would add the solver of this question to this publication.  In the paper, I'm using the Weibull function to model a PCR reaction.

Here is the code for the exponential increasing instance:

```
  # first import the raw data:
  # I pull it from Excel

> CCrelative <- read.xlsx('CC relative fold increase.xlsx', 1)
> colnames(CCrelative) <- c("MolOffTarget", "x1", "x2")
> print(CCrelative)
   #here it is after the import

      MolOffTarget    x1    x2
    1      50001.0 8.474 8.372
    2       5001.0 7.795 7.617
    3        501.0 7.090 7.291
    4         56.0 6.258 4.803
    5          6.0 2.093 1.890
    6          1.5 0.911 0.679
    7          1.1 0.480 0.508


  #now set the minimum of each column to 0 by subtracting the lowest value from each
> CClog0 <- transform(CCrelative, x1 = (x1-(CCrelative[7,2])), x2=(x2-(CCrelative[7,3])))
      #now normalize to the maximum value 
> CClogT <- transform(CClog0, x1 = (x1/(CClog0[1,2])), x2=(x2/(CClog0[1,3])))
      # now make the first column log10 scale
> CClogT <- transform(CClogT, MolOffTarget = log10(MolOffTarget))
      #now merge columns x1 and x2 into a new data frame
> CClogT2 <- data.frame(rep(CClogT$MolOffTarget, 2), c(CClogT$x1,CClogT$x2))
> colnames(CClogT2) <- c("MolOffTarget", "FAM")
> CClogT2.W2.2 <- drm(FAM ~ MolOffTarget, data = CClogT2, fct = W2.2())
```

Here is the code for the exponential decay:

```
> CCvicRelative <- read.xlsx('CCvicRelative fold increase.xlsx', 1)
> colnames(CCvicRelative) <- c("MolOffTarget", "x1", "x2")
> print(CCvicRelative)

  MolOffTarget     x1     x2
1      50001.0 -0.717 -0.706
2       5001.0 -0.565 -0.567
3        501.0 -0.360 -0.349
4         56.0 -0.001  0.584
5          6.0  1.568  1.582
6          1.5  1.767  1.822
7          1.1  1.802  1.844
      #now set the minimum of each column to 0 by subtracting the lowest value from each
> CCvic0 <- transform(CCvicRelative, x1 = (x1-(CCvicRelative[1,2])), x2=(x2-(CCvicRelative[1,3])))
      #now normalize to the maximum value 
> CCvicT <- transform(CCvic0, x1 = (x1/(CCvic0[7,2])), x2=(x2/(CCvic0[7,3])))
      # now make the first column log10 scale
> CCvicTlog <- transform(CCvicT, MolOffTarget = log10(MolOffTarget))
      #now merge columns x1 and x2 into a new data frame
> CCvicT2 <- data.frame(rep(CCvicTlog$MolOffTarget, 2), c(CCvicTlog$x1,CCvicTlog$x2))
> colnames(CCvicT2) <- c("MolOffTarget", "VIC")
> CCvicT2.W2.2 <- drm(VIC ~ MolOffTarget, data = CCvicT2, fct = W2.2())
```

Apologies it's coming up a bit funny on this HTML.

It took me a bit to get used to this package.  I was using Bioconductor packages before.

I made a mistake with the Weibull function earlier. The correct one is now present.

Comment: This is either algebra or numeric root finding.  Either you find the analytic/symbolic expression, or you find $ f_1(x) - f_2(x)=0$.

Comment: If you could add a code-example of how you calculate the b's and e's with the `drc` package, I could help you writing the bootstrap function with `R` (with `boot`).

Comment: I could email you the code COOLSerdash

Comment: The code is a bit long, but posting it would be better for others to look at

Comment: This was the code used

Comment: It starts with importing the following data frame:

Comment: sorry the carriage return is cutting this up

Comment: Given the N of 2 for each value, bootstrapping will work but will it give much?

Comment: @BST Avoid using the term 'intercept' for both the $b$ and $e$ parameters; it's very confusing. Oh and you can't type returns in comments.

Comment: Hi Glen, agreed 'intercept' is  strange way to have the values, somehow R likes to have things are intercepts, when they are values in functions.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The intersection point

The intersection point $x^{*}$ of the two functions $f_{1}(x)$ and $f_{2}(x)$ with parameters $b_{1}, e_{1}$ and $b_{2}, e_{2}$ is given by:
$$
x^{*}=\exp\left[(b_{1}\log(e_{1})-b_{2}\log(e_{2}))/(b_{1}-b_{2})\right]
$$

Here is a small `R` script depicting your example:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The parameters
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

b1 <- -2.226194
e1 <- 1.209326

b2 <- 1.616248
e2 <- 1.837511

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setting up a plot
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

x <- seq(0, 5, by=.01)

f <- function(x,e, b){
  1-exp(-exp(b*(log(x) - log(e))))
}

par(bg="white", cex=1.2)
plot(f(x, e1, b1)~x, type="l", ylim=c(0, 1),
las=1, lwd=2, ylab="Function value")
lines(f(x, e2, b2)~x, col="steelblue", lwd=2)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Calculate the intersection point
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

x.meet <- exp((b1*log(e1)-b2*log(e2))/(b1-b2))
x.meet
[1] 1.442003

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Check if the intersection point corresponds with the graphic
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

abline(v=x.meet)
axis(side=1, at=x.meet, label=round(x.meet,2),
font=3, col.axis="purple")
f(x.meet, e1, b1)
[1] 0.49129
f(x.meet, e2, b2)
[1] 0.49129
```

[image: Weibull2]

---

### Confidence intervals

Here is the code I've come up with to perform the non-parametric bootstrap in `R`(note: I have copied your data into csv-files):

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Load packages
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

library(drc)
library(boot)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Load data and prepare them
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

path <- "F:/" # change path according to your system

CCrelative <- read.table(paste(path, "CC relative fold increase.csv", sep=""), header=T, sep=";")

CClog0 <- transform(CCrelative, x1 = (x1-(CCrelative[7,2])), x2=(x2-(CCrelative[7,3])))
CClogT <- transform(CClog0, x1 = (x1/(CClog0[1,2])), x2=(x2/(CClog0[1,3])))
CClogT <- transform(CClogT, MolOffTarget = log10(MolOffTarget))

CClogT2 <- data.frame(rep(CClogT$MolOffTarget, 2), c(CClogT$x1,CClogT$x2))

colnames(CClogT2) <- c("MolOffTarget", "FAM")
CClogT2.W2.2 <- drm(FAM ~ MolOffTarget, data = CClogT2, fct = W2.2())

CCvicRelative <-read.table(paste(path, "CCvicRelative fold increase.csv", sep=""), header=T, sep=";")

#now set the minimum of each column to 0 by subtracting the lowest value from each

CCvic0 <- transform(CCvicRelative, x1 = (x1-(CCvicRelative[1,2])), x2=(x2-(CCvicRelative[1,3])))

#now normalize to the maximum value 
CCvicT <- transform(CCvic0, x1 = (x1/(CCvic0[7,2])), x2=(x2/(CCvic0[7,3])))

# now make the first column log10 scale
CCvicTlog <- transform(CCvicT, MolOffTarget = log10(MolOffTarget))

#now merge columns x1 and x2 into a new data frame
CCvicT2 <- data.frame(rep(CCvicTlog$MolOffTarget, 2), c(CCvicTlog$x1,CCvicTlog$x2))
colnames(CCvicT2) <- c("MolOffTarget", "VIC")
CCvicT2.W2.2 <- drm(VIC ~ MolOffTarget, data = CCvicT2, fct = W2.2())

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Combine the data into one data frame
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

combined.data <- data.frame(
  MolOffTarget=c(CClogT2$MolOffTarget, CCvicT2$MolOffTarget),
  values=c(CClogT2$FAM, CCvicT2$VIC), 
  ind=c(rep("FAM", 14), rep("VIC", 14)))

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The bootstrap function
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

intersection_boot_fun <- function(data, indices) {

  data.temp <- data[indices,]

  fitFAM <- drm(data.temp$values[data.temp$ind=="FAM"] ~ data.temp$MolOffTarget[data.temp$ind=="FAM"] ,  fct = W2.2())
  fitVIC <- drm(data.temp$values[data.temp$ind=="VIC"] ~ data.temp$MolOffTarget[data.temp$ind=="VIC"] ,  fct = W2.2())

  coefFAM <- coef(fitFAM)
  coefVIC <- coef(fitVIC)

  b1 <- as.numeric(coefFAM[1])
  e1 <- as.numeric(coefFAM[2])

  b2 <- as.numeric(coefVIC[1])
  e2 <- as.numeric(coefVIC[2])

  x.intersect <- exp((b1*log(e1)-b2*log(e2))/(b1-b2))

  x.intersect

}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Bootstrapping and inspecting the results
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

results <- boot(data=combined.data, statistic=intersection_boot_fun, R=50000, strata=combined.data$ind)

results

Bootstrap Statistics :
    original     bias    std. error
t1* 1.442003 0.03151577   0.1268457

#jack.after.boot(results) # influential observations

plot(results)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# BCa confidence intervals
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

boot.ci(results, conf=c(0.95, 0.99), type="bca")

Intervals : 
Level       BCa          
95%   ( 1.303,  1.708 )   
99%   ( 1.258,  1.844 )
```

The output of the bootstrap gives the original estimate, which is about 1.44 in this case. It also gives the bias, which is the difference between the mean of the bootstrap samples (which is about 1.474 in this case) and the original estimate. Technical note: The bootstrapped samples are stored in `results$t` and the mean could be calculated by `mean(results$t)`. The standard deviation of the bootstrap samples is also provided, it is about 0.13. The [bootstrap bias-corrected and accelerated (BCa)](http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~chrisw/stat514/BootstrapCImethods1.pdf) gives a 95%-CI from 1.30 to 1.71. We can't use a normal approximation to calculate the confidence interval, as the bootstrap samples are clearly not normal:

[image: Bootstrap diagnostics]

Comment: I need to run the scripts, but this looks good.  I learned alot from this.  I'm charting a bit of new territory here.  In a typical dose response one looks at 1/2 the maximum values, the so called effective dose 50%, or ED50.  This situation is special in that both things we measure VIC and FAM fluorescence are linked biologically, so I think it is more valid to measure where the two lines cross.  Incidentally, the ED50 of each of the lines are: 26.66 and 29.15.   Hmmm when I enter the log10 values of these x values, which is how it was plotted in my graphs, I'm not getting the same value

Comment: The value of the log10(x) of the ED50's should be 0.5.   I need to revisit what the equation for a two parameter type 2 Weibull is.   In the package notes its described as the equation above...  Some more sleuthing is needed.

Comment: @BST I only know the situation where you estimate the ED50 or LD50 via logistic regression (e.g. [here](https://perswww.kuleuven.be/~u0018341/documents/bioscent_february2011.pdf) or [the documentation of `drm`](http://www.bioassay.dk/index-filer/start/DraftDrcManual.pdf)). In any case, keep us updated about your progress, maybe I can help further.

Comment: I'll look for the equation and see if I can recapitulate what you did here COOLSerdash.   If the answer is 29.75, I think it might not work as I thought previously.  I was thinking it might be smaller...

Comment: The more I look at this the more it looks correct.  I can't get the first function to work though.  Something is amiss when I enter my values.  The first equation is actually this:   {f <- function(x,e,b){1-exp(-exp(b*(log(x)-log(e))))}}

Comment: @BST Thanks for your feedback. What exactly doesn't work? The function `f`? What is the code that fails?

Comment: The function f was not working.  Which is what the 'meeting' point equation was derived from correct?

Comment: Sorry I had the wrong Weibull function for the W2.2 in {drc}.  I have the correct one now, as my ED50 values work with the function f added to the start of the post and the comment above.

Comment: This looks correct.

Comment: COOLSerdash.  This is great.  I'll check with double check the result with my local stats department, but would you like an aknowledgment or an authorship?

Comment: Looks like maybe the old standard of using 1/2 the max will be valid, given the confidence intervals on the meeting point. The 1/2 max is within this region and this value we have is possibly due to experimental error....  Interesting.

Comment: After looking at my data more... It looks like the equation of for the DRC package in R uses a different equation for a Weibull type 2 two parameter regression.  I'm trying to find the correct one.  My original equation gives the same result around the 0.5 = y area, but the curves do not fit further out...

Comment: No the equations do fit.  It is just a bit of a mind warp, as the ED80 on the decreasing slope line, is actually 0.2 VIC fluorescence.  so ED is the dose giving X% of the effect from the starting value.  It works.  Yeha

Comment: @BST That's great news! Uff :)

Comment: One last comment.  the bootstrap call should read this:

Comment: x.intersect <- exp((b1*log(e1)-b2*log(e2))/(b1-b2))